# Running a test category from the Visual Studio UI

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2013

I have a set of unit test , marked with category attribute like so:

```
[TestCategory("Bugs"), TestMethod]
```

I can run the tests from the console as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx.

And I Run them locally using post build events when needed, Is there a way to integrate the `TestCategory` Into the visual studio Test Explorer?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In your Test Explorer, right click and select "Group by -> Traits".

[image]

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx)

Comment: As of VS 15.6+ you will need to turn off `Show Test Hierarchy` to enable the above. Its icon is to the right of the `Run Tests After Build` icon at the top.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is group them, click on the icon to the right of the "Run Tests After Build" icon and select "Traits".  You'll see them sorted by TestCategories.

Update: Confirmed that this also works for VS2012 (in addition to VS2013)